# Доработать консольное приложение

Tags: c#

Задание звучало так: Спроектируйте и реализуйте консольное приложение, для преобразования числа из одного формата «входного» в другой формат «выходной». Входной формат - p, выходной формат 10, Основание системы счисления р - 16.

При вводе A, F и т.п. пишет, что данное значение не принадлежит 16-ричной сс. Помогите исправить, пожалуйста

```
    int s1 = 16; //Система счисления из которой переводим  
    int s2 = 10; //Система счисления в которую переводим  
    string Input; //Введенное число  
    string Np = ""; //Выходное число  
    Console.Write("Введите число в 16 сс: "); //Ввод числа с клаиатуры  
    Input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (CheckInput(s1, Input) == 1)
    //проверяет, принадлежит ли число 16 сс  
    {
        Np = convertNumSys(Input, s1, s2);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nПосле преобразования {0} из {1} сс в {2} сс получили: {3}", Input, s1, s2, Np);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введенное число {0} не принадлежит системе счисления {1}", Input, s1);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
static string convertNumSys(string s, int inBase, int outBase)
{
    string res = ""; // хранит ответ, переменная  
    double dig = 0; // хранит текущии символ входнои строки  
    double temp, k; // хранит значение полученное после перевода из заданнои системы счисления в десятичную  
    temp = 0;
    int z;
    double w = 0;
    temp = double.Parse(s);
    z = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(temp));
    k = temp - z;
    int q = 0;//степень тройки  
    double r = 0;
    while (z != 0)
    {
        dig = z % outBase;
        dig = dig * Math.Pow(inBase, q);
        q++;
        r = r + dig;
        z = z / outBase;
    }
    if (intLength(s) != s.Length - 1)
    {
        if (s[intLength(s) + 1] == ',')
        {
            //res += ",";  
            double l;
            int t = -1;
            for (int i = intLength(s); i <= s.Length; i++)
            {
                k = k * outBase;
                l = Math.Truncate(k);
                k = k - l;
                l = l * Math.Pow(inBase, t);
                t--;
                w = w + l;
            }
        }
    }
    r = r + w;
    res += r;
    return res;
}
static int CheckInput(int b1, string Digit)
//Проверка принадлежит ли введенное число данной системе счисления  
{
    int temp;
    int Condition = 1;
    if (Digit[0] == ',')
    {
        Condition = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = intLength(Digit); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            temp = Convert.ToInt32(Digit[i]);
            if ((temp >= 48) && (temp <= 60))
                temp = temp - 48;
            if ((temp > (b1 - 1)) || (temp < 0))
            {
                Condition = 0;
            }
        }
        for (int i = intLength(Digit) + 2; i <= Digit.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            temp = Convert.ToInt32(Digit[i]);
            if ((temp >= 48) || (temp <= 60))
                temp = temp - 48;
            if ((temp > (b1 - 1)) || (temp < 0))
            {
                Condition = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return Condition;
}
static int intLength(string Digit)
//Длина целой части  
{
    int K = Digit.Length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Digit.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Digit[i] == ',')
        {
            K = i;
        }
    }
    if (K == Digit.Length - 1)
    {
        return K = Digit.Length - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return K - 1;
    }
```

Comment: я ничего не понял. Зачем тут так много кода? В чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: @tym32167 так много кода требуют преподы :( Проблема в том, что не получается добавить латинские буквы, т.е. при вводе в консоль, например, A выводится не 10, а ошибка. Надеюсь, Вы меня поняли. А упрощять коды студенты разучились

Comment: ну это логично, вы же пытаетесь все время конвертровать строку в число `Convert.ToInt32(Digit[i]);`, даже если в этой строке числа нет, а только буквы. Остальной код ваш непонятен, так как там какое то магические числа и сравнения с запятой, непонятные функции с длинами, какие то повторяющиеся циклы, переменные, которые ни о чем не говорят (`temp`? `condition`?) и тд

Comment: я бы на вашем месте 1) Перевел бы пару-тройку чисел из 16 в 10 на бумажке 2) На той же бумажке составил бы все шаги, что я делал, пока переводил числа 3) Закодил бы эти шаги в коде

Answer (score 3):

Накатал на коленке простейший пример. Он может не все ваши случаи покроет, но подойдет как начальная точка.

```
int ConvertFrom16to10(string n)
{
    var mult = 1;
    var ret = 0;
    for (int i = n.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ret += mult * ConvertFrom16to10(n[i]);
        mult *= 16;
    }
    return ret;
}

int ConvertFrom16to10(char n)
{
    if (n >= '0' && n <= '9') return n - '0';
    if (n >= 'A' && n <= 'F') return n - 'A' + 10;
    throw new ArgumentException($"{n} is not 16x value");
}
```

Как использовать

```
var str = Console.ReadLine();   
Console.WriteLine(ConvertFrom16to10(str));
```

Ввод

```
3AF
```

Вывод

```
943
```